# Does GPflow 2.0 support putting priors on (hyper)parameters of GPs?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, gaussian, gpflow

I would like to put some prior on the (hyper)parameters of the GP models in GPflow, but I cannot find any module (like gpflow.priors) or doc about this issue.

Besides, I noticed that `prior` is one of the arguments of the [class parameter](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/a198764d941687bea9a0efa74773bff804bfdb44/gpflow/base.py#L87), together with a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57067948/interpreting-priors-on-constrained-parameters-in-gpflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPflow 2.0 uses tensorflow_probability distributions objects for the priors, e.g.

```py
model.kernel.lengthscales.prior = tensorflow_probability.distributions.Gamma(
    gpflow.utilities.to_default_float(1.0), gpflow.utilities.to_default_float(1.0)
)
```

(or pass the distribution object as the `prior` argument of the gpflow.Parameter class). Note that TensorFlow by default uses float32, whereas with GPs we typically want to work in float64 - hence the calls to `to_default_float`.

This is mentioned in the documentation, both in the [notebook on understanding models](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/understanding/models.html) and discussed in depth in the [notebook on how to use MCMC with GPflow](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/mcmc.html).